# Ajax - показать кнопку если файл существует

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Как показать кнопку если файл существует на сервере или скрыть кнопку если файла нет (можно с jquery или без), при этом периодически проверять наличие файла? Можно проверить как локально, так и по URL.

Comment: а что на стороне сервера крутится-вертится?

Comment: на сервере стоит Apache и PHP

Answer (score 1):

Вот серверная часть, например имя файла `file_exists.php` :

```
<?php    

    $filename = $_GET['filename'];

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo 'show';
    } else {
        echo "hide";
    }

?>
```

А вот клиентская часть:

Например у нас есть тег и он изначально скрыт:

```
<button class="file_exists_button hide">Existing file</button>
```

Вот код на `jquery` который периодически (каждые 10 секунд) проверяет наличие файла:

```
<script>

    var timerId = setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'file_exists.php?filename=sample1.txt', //Здесь нужно задать `url` файла обработки `ajax` запроса
            success: function(data) {
              $('.file_exists_button').removeClass('show').removeClass('hide').addClass(data);
            }
        });

    }, 10000);

</script>
```

А это кусок `css` для показа и скрытия кнопки:

```
.show{
    display: block;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: removeClass('show')removeClass('hide') точку забыл

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик спасибо

Comment: Метод только на GET нужно поменять вместо $_POST

Comment: А можно как-то сделать чтобы по умолчанию при загрузке кнопка была display: none; ?

Comment: Ну так дайте ему класс `hide` изначально

Comment: Понял, да . Ступил немного.

Answer (score 0):

Можно брать `head` файла аяксом, чтобы не загружать его полностью:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/myfile.html',
    success: function() {
        $('.btn').show();
    },  
    error: function() {
        $('.btn').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим на сервере PHP. создаем "example.php" в нем возвращаем true если файл есть, false если нет.

Спёрто у @Razmik Galstyan `example.php`:

```
<?php    
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

и сторона клиента, где ".selector" ваш селектор на кнопку:
[JQ Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
Можно сделать периодический запрос, и вызвать `AutoUpdateTime` **!!ТОЛЬКО 1 РАЗ!!** после ответа или ошибки запрос повториться через 10 секунд (10000мс)

```
function AutoUpdateTime() {
  $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data=="true")
        $(".selector").show();
      else
        $(".selector").hide();
      //Происходит при ответе
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //Происходит при ошибке
    })
    .always(function(datajqXHR, textStatus, jqXHRerrorThrown ) {
      setTimeout(AutoUpdateTime, 10000);
    });
  }  
}
```

Если файл доступен не только на стороне сервера, то можно воспользоваться решением @Artem Gorlachev